# C# GUI without .NET

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I am wanting to develop a Windows GUI program which graphically represents data read from a file. I already have an application that does this, but it does it very badly and with C++/MFC.

I could attempt to edit this application to do what I want it to, but I have no knowledge of MFC and am much more comfortable with C# than C++ so would prefer to rebuild from scratch.

The problem is, I don't want to need the .NET framework installed in order to run this application. This cuts out any use of WinForms or WPF, so I was wondering if there are any similar GUI APIs for C# which I can use for this which do not use .NET?

EDIT: I may need portability to a Linux machine too, now. If I use Qt with C++ I can compile for Windows or Linux, right?

Comment: C# itself requires .Net.

Comment: You realise of course, C# generally is a .NET language and depends on .NET? There's a few rare cases like MonoTouch which will compile to something else.

Comment: And, AFAIK, C++ requires the C++ runtime (or is it available on Windows by default?).

Comment: The closest you could come is Mono in most cases, and that's still a framework install.

Comment: Hmm. I realized after asking that it was a stupid question. Sorry.

Comment: Even simple strings require .NET. You can't skip .NET if you use C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you will need the .NET frameworks or an alternative like Mono to run a C# application.
You could go with a lower version of the framework, let's say 2.0 instead of 4.5, which is installed by default on XP and higher.

[Edit]

Giving it another thought, i remember there was some kind of portable .NET framework being developed, not sure if this ever came to a stage where it is fully stable, but might be something worth checking out if you really really would want something in that direction.

Comment: Apparently Win7 has 3.5 and below all pre-installed. I wasn't aware of this. I guess I'll just use WPF.

Answer (score 0):

[C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1zx9t92.aspx) is an elegant and type-safe object-oriented language that enables developers to build a variety of secure and robust applications that run on the .NET Framework. Without .net framework C# program will not work(expect you can use MONO, but MONO is still framework)

So if you want framework independence, C# is wrong choose
You may want to use lower versions of framework, because all win xp machines have .net 2 installed, in this case you can use WinForm which is supported by .net 2